# Variant of Subset-Sum

Tags: algorithm, set, subset-sum

Given `3` positive integers `n, k, and sum`, find exactly `k` number of distinct elements `a_i`, where
`a_i \in S, 1 <= i <= k, and a_i \neq a_j for i \neq j`
and, `S` is the set
`S = {1, 2, 3, ..., n}`
such that
`\sum_{i=1}^{k}{a_i} = sum`
I don't want to apply brute force (checking all possible combinations) to solve the problem due to exponential complexity. Can someone give me a hint towards another approach in solving this problem? Also, how can we exploit the fact the set `S` is sorted?
Is it possible to have complexity of `O(k)` in this problem?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You are expected to show some own effort befor getting answers. What have you tried so far? Can you show code samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

unsigned long int arithmeticSum(unsigned long int a, unsigned long int k, unsigned long int n, unsigned long int *A);
void printSubset(unsigned long int k, unsigned long int *A);

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long int n, k, sum;
    // scan the respective values of sum, n, and k
    scanf("%lu %lu %lu", &sum, &n, &k);
    // find the starting element using the formula for the sum of an A.P. having 'k' terms
    // starting at 'a', common difference 'd' ( = 1 in this problem), having 'sum' = sum
    // sum = [k/2][2*a + (k-1)*d]
    unsigned long startElement = (long double)sum/k - (long double)k/2 + (long double)1/2;
    // exit if the arithmetic progression formed at the startElement is not within the required bounds
    if(startElement < 1 || startElement + k - 1 > n)
    {
        printf("-1\n");
        return 0;
    }
    // we now work on the k-element set [startElement, startElement + k - 1]
    // create an array to store the k elements
    unsigned long int *A = malloc(k * sizeof(unsigned long int));
    // calculate the sum of k elements in the arithmetic progression [a, a + 1, a + 2, ..., a + (k - 1)]
    unsigned long int currentSum = arithmeticSum(startElement, k, n, A);
    // if the currentSum is equal to the required sum, then print the array A, and we are done
    if(currentSum == sum)
    {
        printSubset(k, A);
    }
    // we enter into this block only if currentSum < sum
    // i.e. we need to add 'something' to the currentSum in order to make it equal to sum
    // i.e. we need to remove an element from the k-element set [startElement, startElement + k - 1]
    // and replace it with an element of higher magnitude
    // i.e. we need to replace an element in the set [startElement, startElement + k - 1] and replace
    // it with an element in the range [startElement + k, n]
    else
    {
        long int j;
        bool done;
        // calculate the amount which we need to add to the currentSum
        unsigned long int difference = sum - currentSum;
        // starting from A[k-1] upto A[0] do the following...
        for(j = k - 1, done = false; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            // check if adding the "difference" to A[j] results in a number in the range [startElement + k, n]
            // if it does then replace A[j] with that element, and we are done
            if(A[j] + difference <= n && A[j] + difference > A[k-1])
            {
                A[j] += difference;
                printSubset(k, A);
                done = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // if no such A[j] is found then, exit with fail
        if(done == false)
        {
            printf("-1\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

unsigned long int arithmeticSum(unsigned long int a, unsigned long int k, unsigned long int n, unsigned long int *A)
{
    unsigned long int currentSum;
    long int j;
    // calculate the sum of the arithmetic progression and store the each member in the array A
    for(j = 0, currentSum = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
        A[j] = a + j;
        currentSum +=  A[j];
    }
    return currentSum;
}

void printSubset(unsigned long int k, unsigned long int *A)
{
    long int j;
    for(j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
        printf("%lu ", A[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: This solution is based on [MBo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/844416/mbo)'s answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An idea how to exploit `1..n` set properties:

Sum of k continuous members of natural row starting from `a` is

```
sum = k*(2*a + (k-1))/2
```

To get sum of such subsequence about needed `s`, we can solve

```
a >= s/k - k/2 + 1/2
or 
a <= s/k - k/2 + 1/2
```

compare `s` and `sum` values and make corrections.

For example, having `s=173`, `n=40` and `k=5`, we can find

```
a <= 173/5 - 5/2 + 1/2 = 32.6
```

for starting number 32 we have sequence `32,33,34,35,36` with  `sum = 170`, and for correction by 3 we can just change 36 with 39, or `34,35,36` with `35,36,37` and so on.

Seems that using this approach we get O(1) complexity (of course, there might exist some subtleties that I did miss)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to modify the [pseudo-polynomial algorithm for subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution).

Prepare a matrix *P* with dimension *k X sum*, and initialize all elements to 0. The meaning of *P[p, q] == 1* is that there is a subset of *p* numbers summing to *q*, and *P[p, q] == 0* means that such a subset has not yet been found.

Now iterate over *i = 1, ..., n*. In each iteration:

1. If *i ≤ sum*, set *P[1, i] = 1* (there is a subset of size 1 that achieves *i*).
2. For any entry *P[p, q] == 1*, you now know that *P[p + 1, q + i]* should now be 1 too. If *(p + 1, q + i)* is within the boundaries of the matrix, set *P[p + 1, q + i] = 1*.

Finally, check if *P[k, sum] == 1*.

The complexity, assuming that all integer math operations is constant, is *Θ(n<sup>2</sup> sum)*.

Answer (score 0):

There is a O(1) (so to speak) solution. What follows is a formal enough (I hope) development of the idea by @MBo.

It is sufficient to assume that `S` is a set of all integers and find a minimal solution. Solution `K` is smaller than `K'` iff `max(K) < max(K')`. If `max(K) <= n`, then `K` is also a solution to the original problem; otherwise, the original problem has no solution.

So we disregard `n` and find `K`, a minimal solution. Let `g = max(K) = ceil(sum/k + (k - 1)/2)` and `s = g + (g-1) + (g-2) + ... (g-k+1)` and `s' = (g-1) + (g-2) + ... + (g-k)`. That is, `s'` is `s` shifted down by 1. Note `s' = s - k`.

Obviously `s >= sum` and (because K is minimal) `s' < sum`.

If `s == sum` the solution is `K` and we're done. Otherwise consider the set `K+ = {g, g-1, ..., g-k}`. We know that `\sum(K+ \setminus {g}) < sum` and `\sum(K+ \setminus {g-k}) > sum`, therefore, there's a single element `g_i` of K+ such that `\sum (K+ \setminus {g_i}) = sum`. The solution is`K+ \setminus {\sum(K+)-sum}`.

The solution in the form of 4 integers `a, b, c, d` where the actual set is understood to be `[a..b] \setunion [c..d]` can be computed in O(1).